# How to create a function to solve two unknowns

Tags: c#, math

Trying to figure out where to start with this. The equation contains two unknowns and the solution for x or y is **always** a positive number.

Given `a = 123` and `b = 55` and c = 5. In this case `x = 31` and `y = 93` but I don't know that ahead of time and I'm trying to write a function in C# to solve it.

```
a - (x + 1) * 96 - (y + 2) + 3104 - c = b
```

Also if `a = 30` and `b = 8` and c = 19 then `x = 32` and `y = 35`

so for:
  Round 1 
      function solveX(123, 55, 5) returns 31
      function solveY(123, 55, 5) returns 93

Round 2
      function solveX(30, 8, 19) returns 32
      function solveY(30, 8, 19) returns 35

Any pointers on where to get started would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: I take it you actually mean "the solution is always a positive integer" ?

Comment: If you don't need only integers, the problem is very easy: You can allways set one of the numbers - say y - to zero and get a - (x + 1)*96 -3104 = b or x = (a-b + 3198)/96. But I don't know what to make of the "THE solution is always positive" - do you need both x,y to be positive?

Comment: @Fernaref - underdefined does not imply not solvable - on the contrary there will be many solutions!

Comment: Sorry there was some missing information that I have now added. I do always need the integer values and I know that a,b,c,x, and y will always be positive integers. Also I don't really care if there are multiple solutions, I just need any valid solution.

Comment: Your solution for `a = 30, b = 8, c = 19, x = 19` is not correct. The correct value of `y` in this case is `y = -63`. In general, the solutions when `a = 30, b = 8, c = 19` are `x = n, y = 3009 - 96 * n`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a linear Diophantine equation. Its solution is very well known. It can be rewritten in the form `ex + fy = d`. Find `g = gcd(e, f)`. If `d = g` then there are infinitely many integral solutions, and these can be found using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). Consequently, if `d` is merely a multiple of `g`, there are infinitely many solutions as well. If `d` is not a multiple of `g`, there are no solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the link. I looked at the example in the link but I think it may not apply because I just realized I left out a variable 'c' in the equation. I've updated the question to show the value of 'c'. Can I still use the extended Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: @ChrisS: Yes. The addition of `c` doesn't change anything. It's still a linear Diophantine equation.

Comment: @Jason: the equation is `96x + 1y = d` and `gcd(96, 1) = 1`. But the solutions x,y obtained using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm are such that one of them is positive and second one is negative. How to obtain both positive solutions?

Comment: @Jiri: In this case, the solutions are of the form `x = n, y = d - 96 * n`. As long as `d > 96`, there are solutions where both `x` and `y` are positive.

Comment: @Jason. Hmm. I'm still trying to wrap my head around this I think part of my problem is understanding where you are mapping n and d to. So if I have (a - (x + 1) * 96 - (y + 2) + 3104 - b) = c where a = 30, b = 19, and c = 8 where does d and n map to? Or, said another way which of these variables is d and which is n?

Comment: @ChrisS: Rewrite the Diophantine equation as `-96 * x - 2 * y = c - a + 96 + 2 - 3104 + b`. Then `e = -96, f = -2, d = c - a + b - 3006`. `n` is merely a parameter that parameterizes the solutions; it comes from the fact that there are infinitely many solutions (since here, `gcd(e, f) = 1` which clearly divides `d`).

Comment: Oh wow. That's a great big help, now I think I actually understand it. Thank you!